# Hibernate Search not working in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-search

I am using Spring Boot and I am trying to use Hibernate Search. I followed this [tutorial](http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/11/23/spring-boot-and-hibernate-search-integration/) but I got the exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   org.hibernate.search.cfg.Environment

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.default.directory_provider=filesystem
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.default.indexBase=/home
```

Pom.xml

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
       <version>5.5.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hibernate 5 has known issues with some Spring Boot versions. You should provide more of your configuration.

Comment: Which version of Hibernate ORM is being used? Hibernate Search needs to be paired with a compatible version of Hibernate ORM. Generally 5.x works with 5.x but it won't work if your version of ORM is much older.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This should solve your problem cause it works well at my spring boot app. Good luck!